# How to place an environment's 2nd+ page(s) at the end of the document

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I'm taking a CS class that has the following requirements for the homework (submitted as PDF output of a LaTeX document):

- Each problem should be on its own page, with the heading "Problem n"
- If a problem goes over one page, include any additional material for that problem on its own page at the end of the document, with the heading "Extra Space for Problem n"
- Add notes: 'Continued on page x' at the bottom of the first page, and 'Continued from page y' on the extra page.

An example of a proper layout for a homework with 3 problems might be:

1. Problem 1
2. Problem 2
3. Problem 3
4. Extra Space for Problem 1
5. Extra Space for Problem 3
6. Extra Space for Problem 3

Is there any way to implement this automatically in LaTeX?

I've already created a document class with environments for the primary and extra page(s) of a problem, which automatically insert the proper heading, labels, notes.

However, it still requires I manage pagination manually. Is there a way to create an environment which will automatically re-order pages beyond the first at the end of the document, and add the proper headers and page references?

Comment: What kind of content will be in the problems? Listings? Images?

Comment: Arbitrary content. It's for a CS theory class, so likely it will mainly be equations, algorithms, and regular text. However, images are possible as well.

Comment: I can change the order of output for the pages by using the `atbegshi` package: at the start of each question, I call `\AtBeginShipoutNext` with a hook which saves the shipout box to a list and clears it. Then at the end, I loop through that list and call `\shipout` on each. However, the page numbers in the footer are all wrong, and I don't know of an easy way to add a reference to the extra page number at the bottom of the first page, and the correct heading and original page number at the top of the extra pages.

Comment: I think it would be useful to see what you're tried so far. It may also shed some light on just how to fix your current problem, rather than re-inventing the wheel altogether. You can [edit your question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/134187/edit) and add the content.